# How to get WKT area?

Tags: java, jts, wkt

i use jts.jar, package is com.vividsolutions.jts.geom, to get a geometry's area. but the method getArea() does not give me the right result. my code is

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        GeometryFactory geometryFactory = new GeometryFactory();
        WKTReader reader = new WKTReader(geometryFactory);
        String s = "MULTIPOLYGON (((114.273193 40.480272, 114.274645 
        MultiPolygon mpolygon = null;
            mpolygon = (MultiPolygon) reader.read(s);
            System.out.println(mpolygon.getArea());
    }
```

Comment: What result did you get, and what were you expecting? It looks like you have longitude latitude coordinates, so a Cartesian area will have units in degrees², which is nonsense. If you are expecting other units of area, you need to use other libraries.

Answer (score 1):

After finding this question when looking for the an answer to similar question, i thought i'd share my findings:

Description taken from blog post as it explains the problem you are trying to solve:

> One of the recurring questions on GIS stackexchange is "What units is
>   the area calculated by JTS `getArea()`". It doesn’t seem to matter how
>   many times people say that these is no answer to this as it depends on
>   the projection of your data. The question will not die, so I cooked up
>   some code that should give a close-ish answer for most polygons.
>
> As with most of these questions the trick is to convert your polygon
>   to a flat cartesian plane (this is where JTS works best). We can use
>   the GeoTools auto projection (assuming the polygon is small enough)
>   and then simply call `.getArea()` method.

Solution:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  GeometryFactory geometryFactory = new GeometryFactory();
  WKTReader reader = new WKTReader(geometryFactory);
  String s = "MULTIPOLYGON (((40 40, 20 45, 45 30, 40 40)), ((20 35, 10 30, 10 10, 30 5, 45 20, 20 35), (30 20, 20 15, 20 25, 30 20)))";
  MultiPolygon mpolygon = (MultiPolygon) reader.read(s);
  Point centroid = mpolygon.getCentroid();
  String autoCode = "AUTO:42001," + centroid.getX() + "," + centroid.getY();
  CoordinateReferenceSystem auto = CRS.decode(autoCode);
  MathTransform transform = CRS.findMathTransform(DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84, auto);
  MultiPolygon projed = (MultiPolygon) JTS.transform(mpolygon, transform);
  Measure<Double, Area> measure = Measure.valueOf(projed.getArea(), SI.SQUARE_METRE);
  System.out.println(measure);
}
```

Output:

```
8.146055550674082E12 m²
```

Reference: https://blog.ianturton.com/geotools,/projections/2017/08/01/area-of-a-polygon.html